# Story of Seasons: I need help: My Sewing Studio disappeared

Tags: story-of-seasons

I have a question. I have already built the Sewing Studio; however, it disappeared. I tried to look around at my farm, but I could not find it. Honestly, it showed me that I made it successfully. So, I would like to know what should I do? I am in the fall season in year 1 now.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a building, it doesn't actually place it on your farm. It adds it to your stock.

You must then go to your workbench and select edit farm. This will allow you to actually place the newly created building.